# WasmTime dotnet - Generic print function in linker

Tags: .net, linker, virtual-machine, webassembly, wasmtime

I am using WasmTime dotnet and want to have a print function defined in the linker that will let me print i32 integer values and string values. Is there any way of doing this?

Part of my Wasm code:

```
(module
  (import "env" "write" (func $write (param externref))) <--- my print function
```

And the c# code look like this:

```cs
_linker.Define(  <-- defining print on host system
   "env",
   "write",
   Function.FromCallback(_store, (int s) => Console.WriteLine(s))
);
```

This then works, but not with strings! and it have to be both!?

```
   i32.const 1
   call $write
```

I have tried:

```cs
_linker.Define(  <-- defining print on host system
   "env",
   "write",
   Function.FromCallback(_store, (string s) => Console.WriteLine(s)) <-- is now a string s
);
```

and then it works with strings... no surprises here.

if i put in something like a ValueType, it says that the function signatur does not match anything in the linker:

```
 function types incompatible: expected func of type `(i32) -> ()`, found func of type `(externref) -> ()`
```

also tried with object.. same result.

I have also tried to define the env:write function twice (one with int and one with string) - this raises an error as well

Hope someone can help! Thanks! :)